# Insert random data string into a new dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

have a df

```
a         b

mark     50

john     60

jack     30

harry     80

jacob     10
```

Need to make a new column in df with some random values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 2d random array of letters and join them in list comprehension:

```
L = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
df['c'] = ['test'+ ''.join(x) for x in np.random.choice(L, size=(len(df), 3))]

print (df)
       a   b        c
0   mark  50  testpje
1   john  60  testrmn
2   jack  30  testoud
3  harry  80  testasw
4  jacob  10  testagx
```